# Back-End MVC (Laravel) Real Time com Json

Tags: php, javascript, json, pdo, mvc

eu fiz um curso de Laravel, e fiz minha aplicação em MVC, porém, existem uns balões, que eu carrego em JSON, clico no botão "login", abre o balão login, nele existem funções de CRUD... Como posso fazer o sistema de MVC, dessa maneira? Os balões estão na pasta views/balloons/... Eu chamo o controller assim:

```
Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');
```

e o controller chama assim:

```
$links = DB::table('links')
    ->join('categories', 'categories.CatId', '=', 'links.LinkCat')
    ->select('links.*', 'categories.CatColor')
    ->get();

return view('site.index', compact('links'));
```

no caso, eu preciso chamar a rota, pelo JSON, pra depois chamar o controller, depois a view que é o balão...

Obrigado!